# Excel VBA copy row to another sheets last row if cell in column A is red

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this problem:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Abgleich blaue Seite")
With ws1.UsedRange
ws1row = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End With
    
    For i = ws1row To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then _
        erow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(erow, 1)
    Next i
```

I try to copy the row from worksheet ws1 to the other ones last row if the cell in column A is red (Index =3)
However, i get errors with my code, and I dont know how to resolve...

Comment: What is the error message and on what line?

Comment: sht.Cells(erow, 1) = < Application defined or object defined error >
In last line before next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `_` from the `if`, it is causing `erow` to be inside the `if` and the copy to be outside.

You probably want `erow` to be `+ 1` as well or you will overwrite keeping only the last loop.

I also recommend adding `ws1.` to `Cells(i, 1)` to make sure you're using the proper sheet.

All together:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Abgleich blaue Seite")
With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1row = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
    
    For i = ws1row To 3 Step -1
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            erow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht.Cells(erow, 1)
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! You safed my day! I really appreciate it. It works now... !!